# IP Address is not validating

Tags: php, filter, ip

PlI don't know why this code is not working:

```
<?php

    $ip = "127.0.0.1";


    if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)  === false) {
        echo("$ip is a valid IP address");
    } else {
        echo("$ip is not a valid IP address");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Could this be the issue: FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE  when trying to validate 127.0.01 ?

Comment: It's actually `FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE` that is failing it.

Comment: Also, what's up with `if(!filter_var....  === false`)?  Why not just `if(filter_var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the flag: `FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE` If your read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) you will see that `127.0.0.1` is reserved, because it's in the reserved range:

> **FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE**   Fails validation for the following reserved IPv4 ranges: 0.0.0.0/8, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.0.2.0/24 and 224.0.0.0/4. This flag does not apply to IPv6 addresses.

Comment: thanks a lot =D

            should i use FILTER_FLAG_IPV4  and  FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 both

Comment: @MISabic You're welcome. You have to decide what you want to filter.

Comment: @MISabic So is your question answered? Or is still something unclear?

Comment: @MISabic As I said depends on what you want to filter, but if you remove the flag `FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE` and use the other 3's I think you're good to go